# get related sub-cat posts on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post type [schools] and a custom tax [location].

Each school is in one location category.

I want to display schools nearby in the sidebar. So far I've worked out how to display 5 other schools but they're not always nearby, which is useless! How can I display 5 schools from that category on my custom single page?

The below display 3 random posts but not in the same category. I hope it can be easily tweaked to work for me?!

```
<?php
// You might need to use wp_reset_query(); 
// here if you have another query before this one

global $post;

$current_post_type = get_post_type( $post );

// The query arguments
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 3,
'order' => 'DESC',
'orderby' => 'ID',
'post_type' => $current_post_type,
'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID )
);
// Create the related query
$rel_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Check if there is any related posts
if( $rel_query->have_posts() ) : 
?>
<h1 id="recent">Related</h1>
<div id="related" class="group">
   <ul class="group">
<?php
// The Loop
while ( $rel_query->have_posts() ) :
    $rel_query->the_post();
?>
    <li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title() ?>" rel="bookmark">
        <article>
            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title() ?></h1>
            <div class="name-date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></div>
            <div class="theExcerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
        </article>
    </a>
    </li>
<?php
endwhile;
?>
 </ul><!-- .group -->
</div><!-- #related -->
<?php
endif;

// Reset the query
wp_reset_query();

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [tax query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)! This snippet also makes use of [`wp_list_pluck`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck), a super handy function for "plucking" properties from an array of objects (in this case, getting an array of term IDs from an array of term objects):

```
// Get current posts location term(s)
$locations = get_the_terms( null, 'location_taxonomy' );

if ( $locations && ! is_wp_error( $locations ) /* Can't be too careful */ ) {
    $schools = new WP_Query([
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'no_found_rows'  => true,
        'post_type'      => 'school_post_type',
        'tax_query'      => [
            [
                'taxonomy' => 'location_taxonomy',
                'terms'    => wp_list_pluck( $locations, 'term_id' ),
            ]
        ]
    ]);
}
```

**Update:** To integrate with your current code:

```
$current_post_type = get_post_type( $post );
$locations         = get_the_terms( $post, 'location_taxonomy' );

// The query arguments
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'orderby'        => 'ID',
    'post_type'      => $current_post_type,
    'post__not_in'   => array( $post->ID ),
    'no_found_rows'  => true, // Performance boost
);

if ( $locations && ! is_wp_error( $locations ) ) {
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => current( $locations )->taxonomy,
            'terms'    => wp_list_pluck( $locations, 'term_id' ),
        )
    );
}

// Create the related query
$rel_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) How do I add it in to the code above? Sorry, I'm pretty new to writing php [i've done a lot of copying and pasting up to now!!]

Comment: See my revision - please try to _understand_ what's going on, and do ask if you want something explained - copy and pasting will only get you so far!

Comment: Thank you so much. It works :) I'm slowly learning about php after 10 years of html. It's slow but i'm trying to understand how and why it works! Thanks again :)